# Disable xsl transformation in Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, xslt

Is it setting in Internet Explorer or group policy that disable XSL transformation when loading XML in Internet Explorer, containing a link to xsl?

I have one computer, where this transformation not work for local files, and for the xml from the Internet. Not errors in IE's development console. Opens only XML source in Explorer's window.

I install MSXML 4 SP3. It did not help.

Internet Explorer 8. Windows XP SP3.

Comment: What happens with that IE if you load http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/processorTest.xml?

Comment: Displayed only XML source

Comment: I am not aware of any setting disabling the application of an XSLT stylesheet to an XML document having an `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction. I would try to compare the IE settings of that machine with the ones on a different machine but with the same OS SP and IE version.

Comment: Thank you! How can I export IE settings for comparing?